# How to solve the differential equation $y''+2y(y')^2=\frac{2x+1}{x}y'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

$$y''+2y(y')^2=\frac{2x+1}{x}y'$$
Not ordinary...
I don't know that to do
Please, help or give an advice

Comment: Divide everything by $y'$, then integrate.

Comment: Do you have limits for integration? This reduces to $\int e^{y^2} dy = \int kx e^{2x} dx$ and the left side cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, if I am not wrong.

Comment: the solution can not expressed by the known elementary functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by dividing both sides by $y'(x)$, then you will obtain:
$$\frac{y''(x)}{y'(x)}+2\cdot y(x)\cdot y'(x)=\frac{2x+1}{x}$$
We can now integrate both sides with respect to $x$:
$$\color{green}{\int \frac{y''(x)}{y'(x)}~dx}+2\color{blue}{\int y(x)\cdot y'(x)~dx}=\int \left(2+\frac{1}{x}\right)~dx \tag{1}$$
For the green integral, substitute $u=y'(x)$.
$$\int \frac{y''(x)}{y'(x)}~dx=\int \frac{du}{u}=\ln(u)+C=\ln(y'(x))+
C$$
For the blue integral, substitute $v=y(x)$.
$$\int y(x)\cdot y'(x)~dx=\int v~dv=\frac{v^2}{2}+C=\frac{(y(x))^2}{2}+C$$
The right hand side integral is trivial. Therefore:
$$\ln(y'(x))+(y(x))^2=2x+\ln{x}+C \iff y'(x)=k_1e^{2x+\ln{x}-(y(x))^2}$$
Separating gives:
$$e^{y^2}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=k_1xe^{2x} \iff \int e^{y^2}~dy=\int k_1 xe^{2x}~dx \tag{2}$$

---

The left hand side of $(2)$ cannot be integrated in terms of elementary functions. However, you can deduce from the definition of the [imaginary error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html) $\operatorname*{erfi}(\cdot )$ that:
$$\operatorname*{erfi}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{t^2}~dt \implies \int e^{y^2}~dy=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\operatorname*{erfi}(y)+C$$
Hence, we have the following implicit solution after using integration by parts on the right integral:
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\operatorname*{erfi}(y)=\frac{1}{4}k_1e^{2x}(2x-1)+k_2} \tag{3}$$

---

We can obtain an explicit solution by using the [inverse imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Inverse_functions) $\operatorname*{erfi}^{-1}(\cdot)$
$$\operatorname{erfi}(y)=\frac{k_1e^{2x}(2x-1)+4k_2}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$$
$$y(x)=\operatorname{erfi}^{-1}\left(\frac{k_1e^{2x}(2x-1)+4k_2}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\right)$$
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{y(x)=\operatorname{erfi}^{-1}\left(Ae^{2x}\left(2x-1\right)+B\right)}$$
Where $A=\frac{k_1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$ and $B=\frac{2k_2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. This can be done since $k_1$ and $k_2$ are arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Divide by $y'$. Then you get
$$
\frac{y''}{y'}+2yy'=2+\frac{1}{x}.
$$
Integrate and obtain
$$
\ln y'+y^2=2x+\ln x+c
$$
Hence
$$
\mathrm{e}^{y^2}y'=c'x\,\mathrm{e}^{2x}.
$$
Then integrate once again...